# PySpark vs Scala Spark vs Spark SQL - Which one is performance efficient? Are UDFs still bad?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have been reading so many blogs trying to understand which out of PySpark, ScalaSpark and Spark SQL is performance wise efficient. Previously, I know ScalaSpark is better because Spark is running in JVM and there is a overhead of Python<->JVM data serialization/deserialization which makes Python less efficient. Does that still hold good?

Scala UDFs can they be created? or are they not performance efficient as it can't be processed by Tungsten.

Also how does Photon engine play a role in performance with respect to these?

I know some of these questions have been asked, but it was like 5 years ago and lot of things have changed in Spark world now.

Answer (score 4):

After going through multiple blogs to understand how Spark works and trying out few things, I now have a better understanding of the Spark platform.

So, Spark uses JVM for running the transformations which means Scala and Java are first class citizens in Spark environment. They usually have a higher efficiency. PySpark is accomplished by running a python process which communicates with JVM and that makes it have a little bit of overhead. But still PySpark is just a wrapper of the Spark API that runs in JVM which means the difference of execution time is close to zero.

As long as the data stays within the JVM (By using PySpark API), there is no performance problems. But when we use plain Python UDF, that's when the data gets transferred between JVM and Python process (serialization/deserialization) causing huge performance gap.

Pandas UDF is much better choice when compare to Python UDF which use Apache Arrow to optimize the data transfer process and in case of Databricks, Pyspark. But this again causes data to be moved between Python process and JVM. So, whenever possible avoiding UDF is the best way.

If it cannot be avoided, Scala UDF > Pandas UDF > Python UDF.

Comment: Hi, is this true for spark SQL as well, i.e in general is scala is better than spark SQL?

Comment: Spark SQL vs dataframe (Spark APIs): Both are converted to same query plans and executed by the engine.

Comment: My question, given a choice to implement in scala versus sql in spark, which would be better to use from performance point of view?

Comment: @Sahil From my understanding, scala would be the best. If you look at the generated DAG, there will be an activity called 'WholeStageCodeGen' which generates the bytecode for the transformations that we run. So ultimately everything gets converted to JVM code, so Scala which natively talks with JVM might be more performant, although it would have a negligble difference with spark SQL

Answer (score 1):

`PySpark` and `spark` in scala use Spark SQL optimisations. In theory they have the same performance. A difference are within UDFs. Here, `PySpark` lacks strong typing, which in return does not allow Spark SQL engine to optimise for types. However there is also an solution with [`pandas UDFs`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html). They allow for type information and the spark engine can with pandas typing optimise the processing logic just like in scala or java.